# org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: org.json.JSONArray, at table: book, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(people)]

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am working on a spring boot library application with mysql,jpa. The database table consists of the following columns bookName,author,copiesTotal,copiesAvailable,people. The problem is with the JSONObject column "people". I want to use the "people" column to store the details of people who borrowed a particular book.

"people" column Eg: {"john":"9876543210", "mark":"0123456789"}

Am I suppose to use any annotations or is there an error in the code?

Here is my code.

**Book.java**

```
@Entity
public class Book {

@Id
@Column(name="bookName")
private String bookName;

@Column(name="author")
private String author;

@Column(name="copiesTotal")
private int    copiesTotal;

@Column(name="copiesAvailable")
private int    copiesAvailable;

@Column(name="people")
//should we use any other annotation here?
private JSONObject people;
//setters and getters omitted

public Book() {

}

public Book(String bookName, String author, int copiesTotal, int copiesAvailable, JSONObject people) {
    super();
    this.bookName = bookName;
    this.author = author;
    this.copiesTotal = copiesTotal;
    this.copiesAvailable = copiesAvailable;
    this.people = people;

}
```

**CONSOLE:**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: org.json.JSONObject, at table: book, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(people)]
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:595) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
... 23 common frames omitted
```

Comment: If you really want to store that as a JSON document, then make it a String, and marshal the JSON object to a String before saving it. But Hibernate is about mapping a relational database. And in a relational database, you would have a Person table containing persons, a Book table containing books, and a Borrowing table containing a borrowing (with a foreign key to Book and a foreign key to Person). All those tables would be mapped as entities. That's what makes it possible to execute queries on the data.

Comment: why don't you create People as an entity with "name" and "phoneNumber" as two attributes. Also as per me you should normalize your schema further by masking People as an all together a different table. You can have 3 attributes: id(primarykey), name, phoneNumber. This way you will just need to store a foreign key reference in Book Table to People table. This will prevent you from anomalies.

Comment: @Hema OneToOne would mean that a person can borrow only one book, and that a book can be borrowed by only one person. That's probably not the appropriate association.

Comment: @JBNizet As you mentioned, a person should be able to take more than one book and each book can be taken by multiple persons. So, I should learn `ManyToMany` mapping first. Thank you all.